# Pass values from visit() to handlePageStatusCode()

Tags: grails, groovy, crawler4j

I am working on groovy and grails project. I have a requirement where I need to pass some values from the `visit()` to `handlePageStatusCode()` in crawler4j. The two methods are inside a class src/groovy/BasicCrawler.groovy class. I cannot change the function prototype since they are overridden. I cannot set the value in session because session variables do not work in src/groovy classes. Is there anything else I can do about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may put that values to some cache, DB, in-memory datagrid or use queue (like RabbitMQ, Kafka and so on).

Comment: Oh, I found your next question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808451/use-session-inside-src-groovy` where you accepted the answer