# Use session inside src/groovy

Tags: function, session, grails, groovy

I want to set a value in session inside a function A() in src/groovy class and use that value inside function B() in the same src/groovy class. Is that possible? I cannot pass the value between functions since they are overridden. I referenced this [link](http://robertbjarum.blogspot.com/2008/10/accessing-session-httpsession-from.html) but did not quite understand the implementation. Thanks in advance.
Edit: Here function A is visit function of crawler4j and function B is handlePageStatusCode()

Comment: "I cannot pass the value between functions since they are overridden.".  That does not make sense.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I meant I cannot change the function prototype. They are overriding functions of crawler4j hence i cannot pass these values as function arguments.

Comment: You cannot just create a class property an assign it before using your methods?

Comment: In crawler4j, it directly goes to the visit function. I cannot use any other custom function inside the BasicCrawler class. It won't be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little utility Java class to handle accessing the session in places like src/groovy, src/java or grails-app/services. You could try using it:

```
public class SessionUtil {

    /**
     * Returns the current session. This can be used in classes where the session variable is not set by Grails, such as Services.
     * @return the session
     */
    public static GrailsHttpSession getSession() {
        return WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getSession();
    }
}
```

To use it, wherever you need the session you would write:

```
def session = SessionUtil.getSession()
```

Comment: As soon as i use this code, my crawler stops working. :(

Comment: What errors are you getting? Any exceptions? Stack trace?

Comment: No nothing. It just stops my crawler from functioning. Whenever i try to use session in my src/groovyBasicCrawler class, my crawler doesnt work. I think its somehow meddling with the crawler4j functionality though I might be wrong. But your approach is good. Thanks

Comment: @ayushi Remember that the session is only accessible on a thread that is processing a web request, i.e. in code that is called (directly or indirectly) by a controller action.  You can't access the session if your crawler is using a background thread.

Answer (score 5):

The link you've referenced is the way to go - the static method [`RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#getRequestAttributes()) will give you the instance of [`GrailsWebRequest`](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest.html) that belongs to the currently-executing request, or `null` if you call it on a thread that is not running a controller action.  Once you have the `GrailsWebRequest` you can access the session, request, response, params and flash (via `getFlashScope()`) from there.

Comment: Thanks .can you share some example for it?

Comment: @ayushi there isn't really anything more to say - `def session = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes?.session`

Comment: @IanRoberts I can't begin to explain how happy I was to find this post.  Thank you very much for this information!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand quite what you are trying to achieve here. A session only makes sense in terms of a connected user, during an HTTP request. If you are using the src/groovy class from e.g. a controller, you could pass the session to your method as an argument to the method. Otherwise how would you be using it?